# What is the Spring JPA EntityManager alternative to "OpenSessionInterceptor"?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

I am working on a project that uses Spring's Hibernate `OpenSessionInViewFilter` and also the AOP version – `OpenSessionInterceptor`. The AOP interceptor is configured for Quartz jobs to provide the same convenience during a job's execution as during a web request.

Now, I am migrating this project from native Spring / Hibernate ORM to Spring JPA with Hibernate as the provider. Though there is an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` provided by Spring ORM (which does basically the same thing as the Session Filter), there is no `OpenEntityManagerInterceptor` or anything similar. I am unable to figure out what is the best approach here, so the question is:

Should I write my own interceptor and/or fiddle with the `SharedEntityManager` classes, or is there another way?

Note: The project is now built with Spring 4.0, JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring has an `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` as the [JavaDoc suggests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html). If the scope of the `EntityManager` shall not be request bound, the usual approach is to build coarse grained components that get an `@Transactional` annotation as this will "bind" the `EntityManager` to the scope of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks! I no longer need the interceptor (it's been 3 years anyway). In my current job we use the `@Transactional` annotation where required, which seems to be the best way to do it.